# An alternative way to rewriting URLs than the Rewrite URL graphic interface in IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7, configuration, url-rewriting

Is there any way to do it, without the user interface? 
I mean a non user interface way, something like a config file hosted in my web site, or some kind of alternative ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, absolutely.

Your URL Rewrite rules should be stored in **web.config** file (unless it is explicitly forbidden which means they will be stored in IIS main config file -- for security and performance purposes, I guess).

Here is an example of such web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="CatchAll" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/catchall.php?page={REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you! One thing less to care!